Properly mock firebase-admin on jest

I have an NX monorepo with jest and node.
I would like to add some unit testing to some code I have and I am required to mock firebase-auth.
I created the following mock under lib/src/__mocks__:
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({
  initializeApp: jest.fn(),
  auth: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    createUser: jest.fn(),
    deleteUser: jest.fn(),
    getUserByEmail: jest.fn(),
    updateUser: jest.fn(),
    setCustomUserClaims: jest.fn(),
    verifyIdToken: jest.fn(),
  }),
  credential: {
    cert: jest.fn(),
    applicationDefault: jest.fn(),
  },
}));


I added the following jest config to my lib.
/* eslint-disable */
export default {
  displayName: 'firebase',
  preset: '../../../jest.preset.js',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[tj]s$': ['ts-jest', { tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json' }],
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^firebase-admin$': '<rootDir>/src/lib/__mocks__/firebase-admin.mock.ts',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../../coverage/libs/external/firebase',
};


then I simply try to mock my stuff
firebase-user.spec.ts
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { UserRecord } from 'firebase-admin/lib/auth/user-record';

import { FirebaseUserRepository } from './firebase-user.repository';

describe('FirebaseUserRepository', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('register', () => {
    it('should successfully create a user', async () => {
      const payload = {
        email: 'test@example.com',
        password: '12345',
        displayName: 'Test User',
      };

      const userData: Partial<UserRecord> = {
        uid: 'XVvwvbn0e0QPLvXXy29k8bmGkq32',
      };

      (admin.auth().createUser as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(userData);
      const result = await FirebaseUserRepository.register(payload);
      expect(result).toEqual(userData);
      expect(admin.auth().createUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userData);
    });

    it('should throw a DatabaseError on failure', async () => {
      (admin.auth().createUser as jest.Mock).mockRejectedValue(
        new Error('Firebase error')
      );
      await expect(
        FirebaseUserRepository.register({
          email: '',
          password: '',
          displayName: '',
        })
      ).rejects.toThrow('Error creating firebase user: Firebase error');
    });
  });

});


with the original file
import { UpdateRequest } from 'firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-config';

import {
  DatabaseError,
  getErrorMessage,
  isFirebaseError,
  NotFoundError,
} from '~myiko/shared/erroring';

import { firebaseAdmin } from '../+services';

export class FirebaseUserRepository {
  static async register({
    email,
    password,
    displayName,
  }: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    displayName: string;
  }) {
    try {
      return await firebaseAdmin.auth().createUser({
        email,
        password,
        displayName,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new DatabaseError(
        `Error creating firebase user: ${getErrorMessage(error)}`
      );
    }
  }

}


and the initializer
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

console.log(admin);
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: process.env['NX_GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
    ? admin.credential.cert(process.env['NX_GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
    : admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});

export const firebaseAdmin = admin;


I can't find a way to set anything up properly.
I tried a multiple way of doing and the last attempt (the one above) now tell me that

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createUser')

What is wrong with my setup, what should I do to have it working and not having to repeat the module mock all the time ?

Modify your mock to look like this.


jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({
  initializeApp: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      verifyIdToken: jest.fn(),
      createUser: jest.fn(),
      deleteUser: jest.fn(),
    }),
  }),
  credential: {
    cert: jest.fn(),
    applicationDefault: jest.fn(),
  },
}));



